# Android make http request within an AsyncTask and post an Array

Tags: android, android-asynctask, hashmap

Seemingly simple question, but no obvious answer found online.

At this link, there is a tutorial on posting simple name value pairs to a file from within an android app. http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

What I want to do is post 'something' which on the receiving end (a php script) can be accessed as an array.

In PHP I want to receive:

$_POST['array']=array("key"=>"value","key2"=>"value2");

Being relatively new to android development, perhaps someone could elaborate on creating a similar thing in Java, and then how one cant send it - setEntity seems to only take namevaluepairs...

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a JSON Wrapper both in Android App and your PHP server.

In PHP you should use `json_decode()`, like: `$thingFromPost = json_decode($data)`.

In Java, there are many ways to create a JSONArray. A basic example would be:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("foo");
list.add("bar");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(list);
```

And after that, you just send your array with a HttpPost to your server.

```
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonArray.toString());
stringEntity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_ENCODING, "UTF-8"));
stringEntity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);          
post.setEntity(stringEntity);
post.setHeader(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
```

If you need a detailed tutorial how to make requests using JSON in Android, follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) link.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But how can you then POST this data when setEntity will not take anything other than a namevaluepair? Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire, raw body of your POST to be the stringified array (and nothing else), I believe you should use a StringEntity instead of a UrlEncodedFormEntity.

So this:

```
String s = "asdf"; // replace this with your JSON string
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(s);
httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
```

I am not familiar with PHP, but conceptually on the receiving end you'll then do something like json.parse(request.full_body). Note that this (request.full_body or the equivalent) is very different from the common pattern of fetching a single value of the POST form like request['input_field1'].

However, reading your question I'm not entirely sure that this full_body approach is what you want. It looks to me like you want to access the data via the form variable 'array', as you indicate here:

$_POST['array']=array("key"=>"value","key2"=>"value2");

Note that you are not working with the entire POST body here, rather instead you are fetching the value of a single form variable called 'array' (I think, I don't really know PHP). If this is the case, then you *should* use NameValuePairs like something below:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("array", yourJSONArrayAsString));
```

This will post the array as a value associated with the form variable 'array' I believe.